# one simple query written in store procedure and same written as inline query which will execute fast.?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

one simple query written in store procedure and same written as inline query which will execute fast in SQL server.
someone from interview panel asked this question from me i said store procedure reason being procedure is compiled but he said i am wrong. 
please explain.?

Comment: No status closed thank you so much...

Comment: It is very kind of you to say "Thank you so much", but on SO it is even kinder to use the votes and acceptance to "pay" for contributions. It is completely free to you, but - if you'd like to do so - it would be kind to chose one answer as "the best" or "the one which solves the issue" and accept it. This will close the question ans "pay" 2 points onto your own account. Once you are over 15 rep points yourself you are allowed to vote on contributions. This is the fuel SO is running with...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, that a *simple query* is some *read-only* code.

- A VIEW is fully inlineable and precompiled. The biggest advantage is, that you can bind this into bigger statement with joins and filters and this will - in most cases - be able to use indexes and statistics.
- A table valued function (TVF) in the "new" syntax (without `BEGIN` and `END` is very similar to a VIEW but the parameters and there handling are precompiled too. The advantages of the VIEW are the same here.
- An UDF returning a table ("old" syntax") is in most cases something one should not do. The biggest disadvantage is the fact, that the optimizer cannot pre-estimate the result and will handle this as *one-row-table* which is - in most cases - really bad...
- A StoredProcedure which does nothing more than a VIEW or a TVF could do as well, is a pain in the neck - at least in my eyes. I know, that there are other opinions... The biggest draw back is: Whenever you want to continue with the returned result set, you have to insert it into a table (or declared table variable). Further joins or filters against this new table will miss indexes and statistics. Might be that a simple *Hey SP give me your result!* is fast, but everything after this call is absolutely down.

So my facit: Use SPs when there is something **to do** and use VIEW or TVF when there is something **to read**